# Broken foreign key constraint prevents deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-migration

I'm getting an error when I try to delete a record:

```
[2] pry(main)> d = Deal.last
[3] pry(main)> d.delete                                                                                                                                           
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "deals" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_78857af2ef" on table "origin_airports"
```

I found an answer on SO that led me to add `has_many :origin_airports, dependent: :destroy` to my `Deal` model, and this fixed the problem.

Well, it fixed the problem last week, and then it came back. If it makes a difference, this is on a record created since last week, though I can't imagine that means anything. I don't think my code has changed at all since I was last able to delete (just working on seeding the DB).

I tried adding this via a new migration: `add_foreign_key :origin_airports, :deals, column: :deal_id, on_delete: :cascade`

And that's not working, but it's possible I don't have a correct grasp on which column/table is which in the `add_foreign_key` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use destroy,

```
d = Deal.last
d.destroy
```

delete will only delete parent record meanwhile if it has child record it's not deleted, if you use destroy it will delete child and parent records so if you delete parent no child record that orphan